# creating custom processors apache nifi

Tags: maven, groovy, apache-nifi

I was creating a custom processor in apache NIFI and in order to do it, I needed to run the cmd: mvn clean install but I have an error

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:59 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-21T11:50:51+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
8.1:testCompile (groovy-tests) on project nifi-pros-test: Execution groovy-tests
 of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile failed
: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1 or one of its depe
ndencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.groovy:
groovy-eclipse-batch:jar:2.5.4-01 from/to bintray (https://dl.bintray.com/groovy
/maven): Transfer failed for https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/org/codehaus/gr
oovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/2.5.4-01/groovy-eclipse-batch-2.5.4-01.jar: Connect to
 d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net:443 [d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/13.225.218.65,
 d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/13.225.218.163, d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/13.
225.218.41, d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/13.225.218.66] failed: Read timed out
-> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
```

any help?? I'm a beginner and I googled it but no solution

Comment: `Transfer failed for https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/org/codehaus/gr
oovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/2.5.4-01/groovy-eclipse-batch-2.5.4-01.jar`

Comment: Hello Maryem, Welcome to StackOverflow! If possible could you please explain a bit more about how you set up the mvn file or which documentation you followed? Would make it easier for the person answering the question so that they dont have to guess the problem! Added a +1 in advance of you editing the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all it takes that instead of passing the command: **mvn install** enter the command: **mvn install -DskipTests !** that's all it take !! because those errors are generated by testing ! so skip the test and all worked super greatly

Comment: I'm not sure what could be causing the error. But I'm pretty sure that skipping the tests is a way to hide the problem rather than fixing it. If you update your question with more details, I'm sure someone can help you to get it sorted.

Comment: no, when I skipped the testes everything worked so great and even the processor that I'm creating created amazingly and now it's working so great ! so if there is any problem it's maybe in some library in my desktop! Anyway thank you very much for your interest and I'm so grateful